# Why is php-fpm trying to connect somewhere on port 443?

Tags: php, http, nginx, centos, selinux

I have nginx and php-fm set up to front a word press site.  I used certbot to setup TLS.

When I load any page, I see selinux violations and it looks like php-fpm is trying to reach out to some port 443 for some reason and getting blocked.

The AVC looks like this:

```
# ausearch -m avc --start recent 
----
time->Tue Nov 24 22:55:16 2020
type=AVC msg=audit(1606258516.914:398337): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=211463 comm="php-fpm" dest=443 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:http_port_t:s0 tclass=tcp_socket permissive=0
```

audit2allow on the violation produces this policy:

```
module somerandomname 1.0;

require {
        type httpd_t;
        type http_port_t;
        class tcp_socket name_connect;
}

#============= httpd_t ==============

#!!!! This avc can be allowed using one of the these booleans:
#     httpd_can_network_connect, httpd_graceful_shutdown, httpd_can_network_relay, nis_enabled
allow httpd_t http_port_t:tcp_socket name_connect;
```

What is php-fpm trying to do here?  How could I find out the host it's trying to connect to?

Comment: I doubt this is php-fpm itself. More likely some PHP code running inside php-fpm. Look at what your code is doing.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich thanks, that's a great point.  This is WordPress.  Although, this site was lifted and shifted to a new machine.  This is exact code (no changes in git) was _not_ doing this before.  At least, if it was, the targeted selinux policies were allowing it because it was not triggering denials.

Comment: If Wordpress have auto-updates enabled, this would be expected.

Comment: Ah, with a packet capture and some testing I am wondering if it's calling out to WordPress for updates or something like you said.  I can trigger it explicitly now by trying to list themes available on WordPress.com.  I don't see any ajax from the client side, so it's gotta be the backend trying to pull that info.  If I `setenforce Permissive` it starts working.  Doesn't prove the original question but I'm feeling a bit better

Comment: Its almost definitely the update check for wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

After doing a `tcpdump` packet capture, I am highly confident that this was two things.  Both things were attempting to contact wordpress.org.  A DNS request would go out for api.wordpress.org immediately before the HTTP request would fire.

1. Listing themes/plugins from wordpress.org
2. Checking for updates from wordpress.org

I believe now the reason this wasn't triggering denials before is because it was under `/var/www/wordpress` which has slightly different default policies.  The new machine went into `/usr/share/wordpress` which seems to have made a difference.

I have left the socket requests blocked and the only harm I have suffered is I can't view available themes/plugins directly from the wp-admin panel.  A worthwhile trade off in my opinion for the security.

Comment: I would add a canary deployment that can access these Wordpress endpoints to be informed when there is an update. (The canary should not be accessible by the internet nor have be deployed with write access for Wordpress.)